# Installing docker on Siemens Simatic IoT2040

Tags: docker, yocto

I am using Siemens Simatic IoT2040 with Yocto image installed. Now, I want to install Docker on Simatic. Could anyone suggest how to install Docker on Simatic IoT2040 running Yocto Linux?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an example of a good question. A good question, requires a detailed description of the problem, coded examples of the current and previous attempts you have made, your current output and your desired output. Questions that are essentially, "How do you do this?" are not acceptable. See : [How to Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
smart update
smart install docker-ce
```

Comment: I have tried installing docker on Simatic IoT2040 using smart command. The reply from device is "smart command not found". Could you suggest how to solve this problem?